# How do I set the text on a button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm making a basic button in WPF, as so:

```
<Grid >

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="23,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=EnteredPassword}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
        <Button Content="Button"  Command="{Binding AddMasterPasswordCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click">
            <TextBlock>Set Master Password</TextBlock>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
```

As such, I get the dreaded 'The property content is set more than once error'
It seems like I should be able to plop a textblock on a button like that. Are there other ways to insert text on a button? Say I want to add "press me" to the button.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `TextBlock` and you set the `Content` attribute in the `button` to be `Set Master Password`?

Comment: Thank you! I'm such a WPF noob I didn't see it at all.

Comment: Cool... if that help you, do you mind a thumbs up on my response :D?

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you remove the TextBlock and you set the Content attribute in the button to be Set Master Password?

Answer (score 0):

I had the content attribute set to "Button" and not to what I wanted. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content attribute or enter the text inside the open and closed button tag, but you can`t do both.

either use this syntax:

```
<Button content="My button" ...>
```

or use this one:

```
<Button ..>
  My button
</Buton>
```